# Mongodb Collections are getting dropped automatically

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I have a replica set instance with one primary and two secondary nodes. I am noticing sometimes random collections are getting dropped. And I observed whenever there is a below entry in the mongo.log, collections are dropped.

**reevaluating syn source because our current sync source's most recent optime more (term: -1, timestamp: Mar  31 08:50:35) which is more than 30s behind member mongodb03:27017 whose most recent OpTime is (term: -1, timestamp: Mar  21 08:51:11)**

Any guesses ??

Thanks,
Rilwan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your servers clocks are not at right time... Use NTP to sync those to right time.

Comment: I understand, but any idea why collections are dropped

Comment: Timestamp points to time when collection didn't exists. DB is rolling back.

Comment: Thanks you so much JJussi